# Save file as Unicode in C# stopped working as expected

Tags: c#, utf-8, type-conversion, utf

I have demo file Encoded UTF-8, which includes special characters:
[image]

I had solution which was converting this file to Unicode (This conversion is necessary so data was displayed by MS Excel correctly):

```
 string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(inputFilePath, Encoding.Default);
    File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, fileContent, Encoding.Unicode);
```

It worked just fine for a long time, but suddenly it stopped working. Currently after conversion data is displayed rubbish:
[image]

I've noticed that data is saved now as **UTF-16 LE**. Any ideas what is causing this issue?

Comment: Why are you reading the file with `Encoding.Default` and writing it with `Encoding.Unicode`?

Comment: In particular, why are you reading it with `Encoding.Default` if you *know* it's in UTF-8? (Converting it to UTF-16 is fine, but using `Encoding.Default` is *usually* a bad idea.)